# Different between left-most and right-most derivation

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I am a beginner started learning theoretical computer science. I just came through *context-free grammars*.

So my question is: what is the different between left-most and right-most derivation?

Because both of them gave me the same parse tree.

Comment: Which grammar and word are you looking at? Hint: look at a non-linear grammar.

Comment: Your question is answered in the Wikipedia article on context-free grammars.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar#Derivations_and_syntax_trees  For future reference, we want you to do a significant amount of research/self-study before asking here -- there's little point in asking questions that are already covered in standard textbooks or online resources like Wikipedia.

Answer (score 18):

Given a derivation tree for a word, you can "implement" it as a sequence of productions in many different ways. The *leftmost* derivation is the one in which you always expand the leftmost non-terminal. The *rightmost* derivation is the one in which you always expand the rightmost non-terminal.

For example, here are two parse trees borrowed from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#/media/File:Leftmostderivations_jaredwf.png):
[image]

The leftmost derivation corresponding to the left parse tree is
$$
A \to A + A \to a + A \to a + A - A \to a + a - A \to a + a - a
$$
The rightmost derivation corresponding to the left parse tree is
$$
A \to A + A \to A + A - A \to A + A - a \to A + a - a \to a + a - a
$$
The leftmost derivation corresponding to the right parse tree is
$$
A \to A - A \to A + A - A \to a + A - A \to a + a - A \to a + a - a
$$
The rightmost derivation corresponding to the right parse tree is
$$
A \to A - A \to A - a \to A + A - a \to A + a - a \to a + a - a
$$

Comment: I have never seen it explained this way around, but I now get your point. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Novice readers may want to note that the underlying grammar $A \to A + A \mid A - A \mid a$ is *ambiguous*. Real-life grammars or such you create yourself for toy examples tend to be unambiguous, and in such there's only one parse tree (and, equivalently, only one left- and one right-derivation) per word. Left- and right-derivation will still differ if the grammar is non-linear, though!